# xmlRoot is not returning a valid element when parsing an html document using XML package in R

Tags: html, xml, r, dom

I'm wanting to parse the html to pull out specific pieces using xpathSApply but the xmlRoot call returns an element whose name is the text of the entire document:

```
> url <- "http://www.achaea.com/game/who"
> doc <- htmlParse(url)
> top <- xmlRoot(doc)
> xmlName(top)
```

Which displays the entire HTML document for the 'name' rather than a root element name.
Can someone tell me what is the cause of this behavior? 
I want to be able to pull out the individual names in the 'honors' hrefs.

Comment: Thanks Randy, you are right, I exited RStudio and started it back up and got your results. This looks like I had some sort of interaction with previously executed code. I should have used rm on doc to have a clean slate. This resolves my problem.

Comment: I thought I misunderstood your question and removed the comment...anyway, see if my answer produces what you want.

Comment: Please consider removing the question since it was not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
xpathSApply(top, "//div[@id='content']//a", xmlValue)
```

If you want to links

```
xpathSApply(top, "//div[@id='content']//a", xmlAttrs, "href")
```